# QEMU guest agent problems - hosts and guests in different versions

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, qemu, libvirt

We have multiple hosts with multiple KVMs each. Some hosts run with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and newer ones with 14.04 LTS. The guests also have different versions like 12.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS. I want to install the qemu-guest-agent on all these KVMs now to be able to freeze the filesystems for backups. I have installed the guest agent successfully on all VMs and added the "Channel qemu-ga" to each KVM xml-config.

Now I have achived the following so far:

```
Host > Guest > Agent
```

---

```
12.04 > 12.04 > OK

12.04 > 14.04 > OK

14.04 > 12.04 > Fail

14.04 > 14.04 > OK
```

What else do I need to install or configure in a 12.04 VM to get the /dev/virtio-ports/org.qemu.guest_agent.0 device after reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel module virtio_console is needed. The VM was using the -virtual kernel, I switched to -generic and now it's working!